# How do I add an extra x-axis to an existing graph?

Tags: excel, axis, extra

I am trying to produce a graph that looks similar to this, with a certain series against a flow (Q), with an added return interval (T). In the example below the "series" is the reduced variate.

[image: Excel graph with extra x-Axis]

When searching online all I find is adding an extra plot line however this isn't what I'm after.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ? This looks interesting but I've never seen it in Microsoft Excel, where do you get this screenshot from?

Comment: @Dominique this was from a lecture on Flood Risk Estimation. As part of my work I've been instructed, using excel, to create a similar graph for different data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that directly in excel, but you can get a similar look by using another series and formatting it to look like an axis

find below a screenshot of a similar example.

[image]